# Firebase notification (рассылка всем)

Tags: android, firebase

Здраствуйте. Чтобы отправить уведомления на андроид устройство на api firebase отправляю такой вот json:

```
{"to":"token","notification":{"title":"title","body":"message","sound":"default"}}
```

Но это отправка на одно устройство по указоннаму токену. Как отправить на все устройства?

Comment: Вы можете подписать все девайсы на топик и слать сообщения в него - придёт оно всем кто подписался

Comment: @ЮрийСПб да я об этом щас парюсь. Можно топик создать через консоль?